# "Error" value on name and description creating strange functionality

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I got a raw data file with its content looking like this:

```
MSN_Check,Text,25,MSN check
0,Text,1,(Result)
HWIMPL,Text,10,HWIMPL version reading
007F,Text,6,(Measure)
1,Text,1,(Result)
VHW,Text,10,FMT hardware version
494131383346,Text,10,(Measure)
0,Text,1,(Result)
TOTAL_VER,Text,25,Total version reading
313031303130,Text,6,(Measure)
1,Text,1,(Result)
CAL_MCU,Text,25,Total version reading
05,Text,6,(Measure)
Error,Text,25,Error
9.8499985089315E-07,Numeric,Float 3.3,(Measure)
CAL_EEPROM,Text,25,Total version reading
05,Numeric,Float 3.3,(Measure)
1,Text,1,(Result)
```

And I needed to extract and store in variables the name, example `MSN_Check` ,the description, example `MSN check` its result for example `0` and its measure , for example `007F` but in some places I have results only or measures only so just spliting them wouldn't have helped.So my idea was:

First of all I created a template table named dbo.template that looks like this:

```
    Name                     TestDescription                     Measure     Result      ID
    ----------------------------------------------
    MSN_Check                MSN check                            0           1           1
    HWIMPL                   HWIMPL version reading               1           1           2
    VHW                      FMT hardware version                 1           1           3
    TOTAL_VER                Total version reading                1           1           4
    CAL_MCU                  Total version reading                1           0           5
    Error                    Error                                1           0           6
    CAL_EEPROM               Total version reading                1           1           7
```

In this table we have the name,description,if_measure(meaning `1` if we have a measure or `0` if we dont) and the if_result.And I made a query looking like this:

```
DECLARE @crlf AS CHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
declare @testname varchar(max),@testDescription varchar(max), @if_measure char(1), @if_result char(1), @row int = '1', @id int
set @LogEntry = (SELECT REPLACE(@LogEntry,@crlf,','))
declare @name varchar(max),@description varchar(MAX), @measure varchar(20), @result char(1)
declare @Output table(OutTestName varchar(max),OUTTestDescription varchar(max), OutMeasure varchar(50), OutResult varchar(50))
declare @maximum int = (select MAX(ID) from dbo.template_FMT)
declare @LogEntry1 as nvarchar(max)
declare @LogEntry2 as nvarchar(max)


while @row <= @maximum
BEGIN

set @name = null
set @description = null
set @measure = null
set @result = null 

set @testname = (select Name from dbo.template_FMT where ID = @row)
set @testDescription = (select TestDescription from dbo.template_FMT where ID = @row)
set @if_measure = (select Measure from dbo.template_FMT where ID = @row)
set @if_result = (select Result from dbo.template_FMT where ID = @row)
set @id = (select ID from dbo.Split(@LogEntry, ',') where Data = @testname)

SELECT @LogEntry1 = Name FROM dbo.template_FMT where id = @row
set @name = @LogEntry1      

SELECT @LogEntry2 = TestDescription FROM dbo.template_FMT where id = @row
set @description = @LogEntry2


if @if_measure > 0 and @if_result > 0

    begin
        set @measure = (select Data from dbo.Split(@LogEntry, ',') where ID = @id+4)
        set @result = (select Data from dbo.Split(@LogEntry, ',') where ID = @id+8)
        insert into @Output (OutTestName, OUTTestDescription, OutMeasure, OutResult) Values(@name,@description, @measure, @result)
    end
if @if_measure > 0 and @if_result = 0
    begin
        set @measure = (select Data from dbo.Split(@LogEntry, ',') where ID = @id+4)
        set @result = null
        insert into @Output (OutTestName, OUTTestDescription, OutMeasure, OutResult) Values(@name,@description, @measure, @result)
    end
if @if_measure = 0 and @if_result > 0
    begin
        set @measure = null
        set @result = (select Data from dbo.Split(@LogEntry, ',') where ID = @id+4)
        insert into @Output (OutTestName, OUTTestDescription, OutMeasure, OutResult) Values(@name,@description, @measure, @result)
    end
set @row = @row + 1
END

select * from @Output
```

And it worked! but the only problem I have is where I have the row with the name `Error` with the description `Error`,it would return the last remembered value so instead of having

```
CAL_MCU    Total version reading         05                    NULL
Error      Error                         9.8499985089315E-07   NULL
CAL_EEPROM Total version reading         05                    1
```

I get:

```
CAL_MCU    Total version reading         05                    NULL
Error      Error                         05                    NULL
CAL_EEPROM Total version reading         05                    1
```

And I would like to store the `Error cant find Result with ID` into variables if any of you have any suggestions :)
P.S. I think it has something to do with the fact that the `name` and `description` have the same name (`Error`)

Comment: I think you need to come up with a much simpler example reproducing the problem/question that you have. Chances are that most people won't be bothered to read it all  Try simplifying it

Comment: And change the question title to something meaningful

Comment: Ok i will try to think of something as soon as I get home. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your problem can be solved without the need for while loops and string splitting functions. I recommend using the OPENROWSET function to read your raw data file as a standard table. You can then use standard T-SQL query to format the result into the desired output.
The first step is to ensure that ad-hoc queries is enable on your server this can be accomplished by executing the following command.

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
RECONFIGURE; 
GO 
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;  
RECONFIGURE;
```

The next step is to define a format file for your text file. This will help SQL Server understand the text file structure when loading the raw data. Based on the supplied sample data your format file should look as follow:

```
10.0  
4  
1       SQLCHAR       0       100     ","     1     Col1             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  
2       SQLCHAR       0       100     ","     2     Col2             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  
3       SQLCHAR       0       100     ","     3     Col3             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  
4       SQLCHAR       0       100     "\r\n"   4    Col4             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

I have uploaded the format file and example raw data file I have used to test the example at the following links:

http://www.filedropper.com/format

http://www.filedropper.com/rawdatafile

The final step is to run the OPENROWSET query to load the file data and transform the data to the desired output. If you are using SQL Server 2008 r2 then the following query should work:

```
-- 2008 R2 Version
WITH  CTE_VariableRawData
AS
(
    SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS ID
            ,[RawData].Col1 AS [VariableOrMeasure]
            ,(
                CASE [RawData].Col4
                    WHEN '(Result)' THEN 0
                    WHEN '(Measure)' THEN 0
                    ELSE 1
                 END
             ) AS IsVariable
            ,(
                CASE [RawData].Col4
                    WHEN '(Result)' THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                 END
             ) AS IsResult
            ,(
                CASE [RawData].Col4
                    WHEN '(Measure)' THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                 END
             ) AS IsMeasure
             ,[RawData].Col4 AS [Description]
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\temp\raw_data_file.txt',  FORMATFILE = 'c:\temp\format.txt') AS [RawData]
)
,
CTE_RawDataByVariableID
AS
(
    SELECT   ID
            ,(
                SELECT SUM([IsVariable]) 
                FROM    CTE_VariableRawData RunningTotal
                WHERE   RunningTotal.ID <= CTE_VariableRawData.ID
             ) AS VariableID
            ,[VariableOrMeasure]
            ,[IsVariable]
            ,[IsResult]
            ,[IsMeasure]
            ,[Description]
    FROM    CTE_VariableRawData
)
SELECT      VariableID
            ,MAX(
                    CASE [IsVariable]
                        WHEN 1 THEN [VariableOrMeasure]
                        ELSE NULL
                    END
                ) AS [Variable]
            ,MAX(
                    CASE [IsVariable]
                        WHEN 1 THEN [Description]
                        ELSE NULL
                    END
                ) AS [Description]
            ,MAX(
                    CASE [IsMeasure]
                        WHEN 1 THEN [VariableOrMeasure]
                        ELSE NULL
                    END
                ) AS [Measure]      
            ,MAX(
                    CASE [IsResult]
                        WHEN 1 THEN [VariableOrMeasure]
                        ELSE NULL
                    END
                ) AS [Result]                           
FROM        CTE_RawDataByVariableID
GROUP BY    VariableID
ORDER BY    VariableID
```

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later then the following query will be a bit more optimal:

```
WITH  CTE_VariableRawData
AS
(
    SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS ID
            ,[RawData].Col1 AS [VariableOrMeasure]
            ,(
                CASE [RawData].Col4
                    WHEN '(Result)' THEN 0
                    WHEN '(Measure)' THEN 0
                    ELSE 1
                 END
             ) AS IsVariable
            ,(
                CASE [RawData].Col4
                    WHEN '(Result)' THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                 END
             ) AS IsResult
            ,(
                CASE [RawData].Col4
                    WHEN '(Measure)' THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                 END
             ) AS IsMeasure
             ,[RawData].Col4 AS [Description]
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\temp\raw_data_file.txt',  FORMATFILE = 'c:\temp\format.txt') AS [RawData]
)
,
CTE_RawDataByVariableID
AS
(
    SELECT   ID
            ,SUM([IsVariable]) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS VariableID
            ,[VariableOrMeasure]
            ,[IsVariable]
            ,[IsResult]
            ,[IsMeasure]
            ,[Description]
    FROM    CTE_VariableRawData
)
SELECT      VariableID
            ,MAX(
                    CASE [IsVariable]
                        WHEN 1 THEN [VariableOrMeasure]
                        ELSE NULL
                    END
                ) AS [Variable]
            ,MAX(
                    CASE [IsVariable]
                        WHEN 1 THEN [Description]
                        ELSE NULL
                    END
                ) AS [Description]
            ,MAX(
                    CASE [IsMeasure]
                        WHEN 1 THEN [VariableOrMeasure]
                        ELSE NULL
                    END
                ) AS [Measure]      
            ,MAX(
                    CASE [IsResult]
                        WHEN 1 THEN [VariableOrMeasure]
                        ELSE NULL
                    END
                ) AS [Result]                           
FROM        CTE_RawDataByVariableID
GROUP BY    VariableID
ORDER BY    VariableID;
```

Note that in both queries you will have to change the location of your raw data file and format file to the desired location within the `OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\temp\raw_data_file.txt',  FORMATFILE = 'c:\temp\format.txt')` call.